# Unity Google VR reticle pointer weird behaviour

Tags: unity, google-cardboard, gearvr

I'm using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and Google VR SDK 1.150.0. I added GvrEditorEmulator and GvrEventSystem to the hierarchy, created an empty object and put main camera inside. I also added GvrRecticlePointer as a child of the camera. Then I added a spinning cube and added EventTrigger script onto it. When I point reticle at the cube in the game mode the reticle pointer start shaking. I'm wondering why is that?

[image]